# Xpath contains ' or '', how to handle?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, scrapy, lxml

I'm crawling a website using Scrapy and would like to scrap items in a table that contain ' or "

```
xpath = '//table/tbody/tr/td[contains(.,\"\'") or contains (.,\"\"\")]/text()'
```

However, this leads to:

```
ValueError: XPath error: Invalid expression in XPATH
```

Is there anyway other way to do this? (I've tried using unicodes for ' and " but it does not work. I've also tried variables to no avail)

Thanks

Comment: You forgot to escape one of the quotes:  //table/tbody/tr/td[contains(.,\"\'\") or contains (.,\"\"\")]/text()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you search for `'` use `"` as XPath string literal delimiter to avoid conflict, and the other way around when searching for `"` :

```
//table/tbody/tr/td[contains(.,"'") or contains (.,'"')]/text()
```

Now, your python also use a kind of string delimiter, for example, using `"`, and you need to avoid that conflicting with `"` in your XPath (the XPath above). Therefore, you need to escape every `"` in the XPath using `\"` :

```
xpath = "//table/tbody/tr/td[contains(.,\"'\") or contains (.,'\"')]/text()"
```

Or, if this is Scrapy, you can use [XPath variable](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#variables-in-xpath-expressions) to specify single & double quotes without escaping :

```
query = "//table/tbody/tr/td[contains(.,$single_quote) or contains (.,$double_quote)]/text()"
response.xpath(query, single_quote="'", double_quote='"').extract()
```